# Extracting the first name, middle initial, and last name from a Full name column

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL and I'm trying to extract the First Name, Last Name, and Middle Initial (if there is any) from a Full Name column. I was able do do this with the following query, but I would like to simplify the query by using variables.

What is the way to use variables to simplify the below?

```
SELECT DISTINCT trim(PROV_NAME) as FullName,
    CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name)) as  FirstSpaceIndex,
    LEN(trim(prov_name)) as FullNameLength,
    SUBSTRING(trim(PROV_NAME), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name))) AS FirstNameExtracted,
    RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name))) as RestOfName,
    LEN(RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name)))) AS RestOfNameLength,
    CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name)))) as FirstSpaceInRestOfName,
    LEFT(RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name))), CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name))))) as MiddleInitialExtracted,
    RIGHT(RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name))), LEN(RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name)))) - CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(trim(prov_name), LEN(trim(prov_name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', trim(prov_name))))) as LastNameExtracted
FROM ARCHIVE
```

Comment: You can't use variables within a single query. You could pass values from a query to a variable, and then use them in the next query you execute. However, that would require to run the above query twice, and account for more than one row being returned.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query uses many product specific functions.)

Comment: I have some extra names to add to your sample data, Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt, Jonathan Rhys-Davies, Sammy Davies Jr. and George W Bush.